# Periodically call function while element is visible

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have a websocket connection (`socket`) that the client should use to regulary update `app.value`. I need to periodically call the send()-function while a specific div is visible and stop calling when it becomes invisible. How can I accomplish this?

```js
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="visible">
        {{value}}
        /* Periodically call send() here while this renders - how? */
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    visible: false,
    value: "Not loaded yet",
    },
    methods : {
        send: function (type, data) {
            socket.send("update");
        }
    }
});

/* the app.value update is already handled */
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval(()=>{ if (this.visible){ socket.send("update"); }, 3000 }`. Better yet would be to start/stop the interval when this.visible changes.

Comment: I would not think of starting/stopping when the div is visible, but rather when the variable `visible` is true or false. You can start and clear the interval with the code that changes the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed ippis' and Mark_Ms' proposals and implemented the functionality within the code that changed the `app.value` variable:

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    var packet = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var type = packet["type"]
    var data = packet["data"]
    if (type=="info") {
        if (app.value!==null) {
            clearInterval(app.watcher)
        }
        app.value = data
        app.watcher = setInterval(send, 1000)
    }
}
```